# Solidity Compiling Error When Using Truffle

Tags: node.js, solidity, truffle

I am new to programming in solidity and was wondering what when wrong with my coding. I was following the instructions on a udemy course on how to make a smart contract. I tried to copy the coding but results in an error which I haven't found the solution to.

Here's what write in my file:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
contract Greeter {
  string greeting;
  function greeter(string _greeting) public {
    greeting = _greeting;
  }
  function greet() constant returns (string) {
    return greeting;
  }
}
```

and this is the script

```
var Greeter = artifacts.require("./Greeter.sol")
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Greeter);
};
```

lastly this is the migration file:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner = msg.sender;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "This function is restricted to the contract's owner"
    );
    _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
```

Here is the produced error:

```
Truffle v5.5.3 (core: 5.5.3)
Node v16.14.0
dennisanthony@Denniss-MacBook-Pro greeter % truffle test
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Greeter.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol

ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'constant'
 --> project:/contracts/Greeter.sol:8:20:
  |
8 |   function greet() constant returns (string) {
  |                    ^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.5.3 (core: 5.5.3)
Node v16.14.0
```

I'm using Node v16.14.0 and truffle v5.5.3 running on macbook pro 2020 M1 OS Monterey version 12.2.1
If anybody has a solution please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
contract Greeter {
  string greeting;
  function greeter(string memory _greeting) public {
    greeting = _greeting;
  }
  function greet()public view returns (string memory) {
    return greeting;
  }
}
```

try this way:

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the respond, this actually works! Would you mind to explain what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to put `view` instead of `constant` in the function declaration.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the respond. I did try this but it didn't work. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

there are two issues:

1- instead of constant:

```
function greet()public view returns (string memory)
```

2- Second issue:

```
   var Greeter = artifacts.require("./Greeter.sol")
```

you are passing the path but you have to pass the name of the contract:

```
 var Greeter = artifacts.require("Greeter")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the respond Yilmaz, both your answer and Nerdy19 works. Thank you for the explaination to the answer provided. It really helps me learning from the mistakes I made.